# Are there some optional wrong here?

Tags: ios, swift

This is the code and the problem

There is no wrong when I did select one row before I add the function tableView(......didSelectRowatindexPath...)

So, I thought it's the root cause.

I hope somebody can help me because the wrong info was not so clear that I can understand it well.

[image]

What I want to do is change the BarItemName when I did select one row of my popover table.

SwitchA is a var in my popoverviewcontroller, it means which button is pressed.

When the button in "SecondVC" is pressed,it will pass a value to SwitchA and then the popoverviewcontroller can determine which datasource it should show.

[image]

PS:this is the popoverviewcontroller's code.

```
import UIKit

class PopOverView: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



var SwitchA = 0
var ClassA = ["这个类型","那个类型","这个类型","那个类型","这个类型","那个类型","这个类型","那个类型","这个类型","那个类型"]
var TimeA = ["昨天","今天","明天","昨天","今天","明天"]
var TagA = ["动漫","音乐","游戏","音乐","游戏"]
@IBOutlet weak var TV: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    TV.dataSource = self
    TV.delegate = self

    self.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 175)
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    if SwitchA == 0 {
        return ClassA.count
    }
    if SwitchA == 1 {
        return TimeA.count
    }
    else {
        return TagA.count
    }
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    if SwitchA == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = ClassA[indexPath.row]
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        return cell
    }
    if SwitchA == 1 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = TimeA[indexPath.row]
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = TagA[indexPath.row]
        cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = false
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
        return cell
    }

}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 35.0
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    if SwitchA == 0 {
        let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! XiaoNei_HuoDong
        VC.ClassName.title = ClassA[indexPath.row]
    }
    if SwitchA == 1 {
        let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! XiaoNei_HuoDong
        VC.TimeName.title = TimeA[indexPath.row]
    }
    else {
        let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! XiaoNei_HuoDong
        VC.TagName.title = TagA[indexPath.row]
    }
}


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

And this is the code of "SecondVC":

```
import UIKit

class XiaoNei_HuoDong: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var TagName: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var TimeName: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var ClassName: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var huodongTV: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    huodongTV.dataSource = self
    huodongTV.delegate = self

    huodongTV.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false

    let options = PullToRefreshOption()
    options.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 239/255, green: 239/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1)
    options.indicatorColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    huodongTV.addPullToRefresh(options: options, refreshCompletion: { [weak self] in
        // some code

        self!.huodongTV.reloadData()
        self!.huodongTV.stopPullToRefresh()
        })
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 3
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 1.0
}
// Row display. Implementers should *always* try to reuse cells by setting each cell's reuseIdentifier and querying for available reusable cells with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
// Cell gets various attributes set automatically based on table (separators) and data source (accessory views, editing controls)
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    self.huodongTV.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let cell:HuoDong_2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("huodong2") as! HuoDong_2
        cell.ClubB1.image = UIImage(named: "test")!
        cell.ClubB2.image = UIImage(named: "test")!
        cell.ClubS1.image = UIImage(named: "focus")!
        cell.ClubS2.image = UIImage(named: "focus")!
        cell.Tag1.image = UIImage(named: "更新")!
        cell.Tag2.image = UIImage(named: "更新")!
        cell.View1.image = UIImage(named: "view")!
        cell.View2.image = UIImage(named: "view")!
        cell.Newest.image = UIImage(named: "club rank")
        return cell
    }
    else {
        let cell:HuoDong = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("huodong1") as! HuoDong
        cell.ClubB1.image = UIImage(named: "test")!
        cell.ClubB2.image = UIImage(named: "test")!
        cell.ClubS1.image = UIImage(named: "focus")!
        cell.ClubS2.image = UIImage(named: "focus")!
        cell.Tag1.image = UIImage(named: "更新")!
        cell.Tag2.image = UIImage(named: "更新")!
        cell.View1.image = UIImage(named: "view")!
        cell.View2.image = UIImage(named: "view")!
        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(1, 1, 1)
    })

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        return self.view.frame.width * 240.0 / 400.0
    }
    else {
        return self.view.frame.width * 200.0 / 400.0
    }
}




// MARK: - PopOverforsegue

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Class1"{
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! PopOverView
        VC.SwitchA = 0
        VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        VC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    }
    if segue.identifier == "Time1"{
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! PopOverView
        VC.SwitchA = 1
        VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        VC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    }
    if segue.identifier == "Tag1"{
        let VC = segue.destinationViewController as! PopOverView
        VC.SwitchA = 2
        VC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
        VC.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
    }
}

func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle {
    return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

}
```

Comment: Please try going through the [MVCE steps](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to narrow your question down. It's very hard to help you when you paste this much code without your analysis and attempted troubleshooting. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is timing of initialize.
Try this:

**SecondVC**

```
var tagNameStr = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    TagName.title = tagNameStr  // here
    ...
}
```

**FirstVC**

```
if SwitchA == 0 {
    let VC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondVC") as! XiaoNei_HuoDong
    VC.tagNameStr = ClassA[indexPath.row]
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

**UPDATE**

This is sample code.
(ViewController -|segue|-> SecondViewController)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let vc = segue.destinationViewController as? SecondViewController {
            vc.buttonTitle = "IOhYES"
        }
    }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var buttonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
    var buttonTitle = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        buttonItem.title = buttonTitle
    }
}
```

Please check IBOutlet connection.

Comment: I did it as you said.It is glad not to see optional wrong anymore.But this way cannot change the BarButtomItem's title.

Comment: In my environment, my method is work. please read edited my answer.